# Redux Thunk Dispatch Axios Post Request Body

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

So I am kinda stuck in trying to send a request body in Redux Thunk using `axios`. The app I work on has a particular setup, and we have a service which exposes backend methods that we can use in a `dispatch` call, like so:

```js
// action file

export const subscribeUser = (id, token) => async dispatch => {
  await dispatch({
    type: t.SOME_ACTION_FETCHING,
    api: 'nameOfApi',
    method: 'createSubscription',
    payload: {
      userId: id
    }
  }).then(
    response => dispatch({ type: t.SOME_ACTION_FETCHED, subscriptionStatus: response })
  );
};
```

Where `nameOfApi` is the backend to communicate with, and `createSubscription` is the appropriate `post` method. What I can't seem to get working is sending a request body in this request.

In the `dispatch` logic, I have tried

```js
await dispatch({
  type: t.SOME_ACTION_FETCHING,
  api: 'nameOfApi',
  method: 'createSubscription',
  payload: {
    userId: id,
    subscribeToken: token
  }
})
```

and

```js
await dispatch({
  type: t.SOME_ACTION_FETCHING,
  api: 'nameOfApi',
  method: 'createSubscription',
  payload: {
    userId: id,
  },
  subscribeToken: token
})
```

So the route I am trying to hit is `https://gateway.dev.url/nameOfApi/{userId}/subscription`. And I am trying to send `token` in the request body.

The following route successfully returns the response I would need when I use Postman to ping `https://gateway.dev.url/nameOfApi/1234/subscription` (*with the appropriate headers, which are already handled by a service*), and in the `Body` tab in Postman, I send

```js
{
  "subscribeToken": "abcd1234"
}
```

which is what the API requires. But in my React/Redux code, I am getting either 500 errors, or 409 errors because the entire request doesn't match the Swagger validation, which the latter proves pinging the API is working, the request is just being sent in the wrong way.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction of how to send `subscribeToken` in the request body of a `post` request with `axios` with Redux Thunk `dispatch`?

Thank you in advance for any potential guidance...!

**EDIT**: And to add, there is also a `get` request which expects only `userId` as a URL param, and the below resolves and returns a successful response:

```js
await dispatch({
  type: t.SOME_ACTION_FETCHING,
  api: 'nameOfApi',
  method: 'getSubscription',
  payload: {
    userId: id,
  }
})
```

So the issue with the `post` is definitely just a syntax problem, in how I would transcribe what works in Postman (*the `Body` tab parameter*), into this `dispatch` logic.

Comment: Which kind of payload does your `t.SOME_ACTION_FETCHING` expect?

Comment: The post request expects a `userId` as a URL param, and a `subscribeToken` as part of the request body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually looks like I was missing a wrapper parameter from the API, and the `dispatch` request needed to look like

```js
await dispatch({
  type: t.SOME_ACTION_FETCHING,
  api: 'nameOfApi',
  method: 'createSubscription',
  payload: {
    userId: id,
    newToken: {
      subscribeToken: token
    }
  }
})
```

So looks I'm all sorted now. Mods can close this question, unless it's informative to the community to keep around.